# Hornetq embedded, Couldn't find any bindings for address

Tags: java, binding, hornetq

I'm using an embedded HornetQ instance from within a JUnit test case.

Somehow I can't get my test driver to deliver a message onto the bus. There is no exception or anything that says that the message bus wasn't working or properly set up(see [1]).

Only when I run the test case in debug mode I'm seeing some traces starting with "Couldn't find any bindings for address..." (see [2]).

Is this trace message something that can be ignored? "No binding" sounds to me like there could be no hornetq available at all.

### [1]

Q221007: Server is now live
[FF] [ScalaTest-run] [2014-06-11 15:03:03,555  INFO] HornetQServerImpl.java:460 - HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.5.0.SNAPSHOT (Wild Hornet, 124) [ea2511b0-e5c6-11e3-a213-b1fcc2ec9262]

### [2]

**Couldn't find any bindings for address=hornetq.notifications on message**=ServerMessage[messageID=5,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, bodySize=512,expiration=0, durable=true, address=hornetq.notifications,properties=TypedProperties[{_HQ_User=null, _HQ_NotifTimestamp=1402491783941, _HQ_Distance=0, _HQ_SessionName=b9525487-f168-11e3-8314-fb544e2d7270, _HQ_NotifType=CONSUMER_CREATED, _HQ_Address=xxx.messaging.RequestMessage-integ-test, _HQ_ClusterName=d78dbd27-bfe8-47f9-8b51-06c4eeb63543-integ-testea2511b0-e5c6-11e3-a213-b1fcc2ec9262, _HQ_RoutingName=d78dbd27-bfe8-47f9-8b51-06c4eeb63543-integ-test, _HQ_ConsumerCount=1, _HQ_RemoteAddress=invm:0}]]@1086110741
[FF] [Thread-0 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=ea2511b0-e5c6-11e3-a213-b1fcc2ec9262-1032009487-1905514837)] [2014-06-11 15:03:03,942 DEBUG] PostOfficeImpl.java:685 - Message ServerMessage[messageID=5,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, bodySize=512,expiration=0, durable=true, address=hornetq.notifications,properties=TypedProperties[{_HQ_User=null, _HQ_NotifTimestamp=1402491783941, _HQ_Distance=0, _HQ_SessionName=b9525487-f168-11e3-8314-fb544e2d7270, _HQ_NotifType=CONSUMER_CREATED, _HQ_Address=xxx.messaging.RequestMessage-integ-test, _HQ_ClusterName=d78dbd27-bfe8-47f9-8b51-06c4eeb63543-integ-testea2511b0-e5c6-11e3-a213-b1fcc2ec9262, _HQ_RoutingName=d78dbd27-bfe8-47f9-8b51-06c4eeb63543-integ-test, _HQ_ConsumerCount=1, _HQ_RemoteAddress=invm:0}]]@1086110741 **is not going anywhere as it didn't have a binding on address:hornetq.notifications**

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing some source code for your test

Comment: Yes, your are definitely right and I thought about posting some code, too. But the problem is there is some handcrafted API code between my test case and the hornet core api itself. Plus some complex Spring configurations that goes along with it. It would be difficult to make all this concise and understandable for a Stacktrace post. Therefore I was hoping for a basic explanation, what this error could mean or when it occurs. I have to take from there I guess.

Comment: This specific code you posted is not an error.. it's debug.

Comment: We send notifications for things that happen on the servers, and you won't always have a listener for these notifications. on this case the notification message is just not being routed as you have no consumers.. which is perfectly fine.

This has nothing to do with the error you're having... it's irrelevant. You should look for other clues on your test.

I'm not giving this as an answer as it doesn't answer your question. I don't have enough info to do it.

Comment: Nonetheless your answer is appreciated and very helpful. So I can rule this out then.

Comment: One question though, could a notification contain any information about important stuff like problems when delivering a message?

Comment: We send notification when consumers are created, queues are created... object states have changed.. etc... not when delivery happens.


I will place my previous comment as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This specific code is just a Log.debug.

```
Couldn't find any bindings for address=hornetq.notifications on...
```

We send notifications for things that happen on the servers, and you won't always have a listener for these notifications. on this case the notification message is just not being routed as you have no consumers.. which is perfectly fine. This has nothing to do with the error you're having... it's irrelevant. You should look for other clues on your test. I'm not giving this as an answer as it doesn't answer your question. I don't have enough info to do it.

I would need more information to answer exactly why you're not receiving messages on your test.. but this specific message you posted has no direct relation.

Comment: For future googlers: At the end, it was my application code causing the trouble. Nothing to do with the hornetq.